# How to install logstash-forwarder for multiple logstash server?

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, filebeat

Currently we are working on forwarding logs to 2 different logstash servers. We cannot figure out a way with which we can install logstash-forwarder on a single machine. Is it possible with logstash-forwarder forwarding logs to multiple logstash ?? 
Else how can we do it with filebeat ??

Answer (score 1):

In the LSF config, you can specify a list of hosts, but it will pick one at random and only switch to another in case of failure.

FB has the same system, but it allows you to also load balance across the list of hosts.

AFAIK, neither allows you to send events to multiple logstash instances.

Logstash, on the other hand, will send events to all of its outputs, so you could have FB send to a single LS, and have that LS output to your other LS instances.  Note that if one output is unavailable, the system will block.